# Zeros disappear with string. - C#

Tags: c#, string, list, decimal, string-conversion

This seems a bit problematic to me.

With my project whenever I input a `decimal` value like `2.12`, and I call a function that validates some other points and returns a `string`.

Now, I `Add` this decimal value in a `List<string>` named as `UserValues`.

But, when I input some value as 0.15, the same function returns `0.15`. But when I `Add` it to `UserValues` it stores it as .15 which contradicts the client requirement.
Or if I input the value as `0.00` then it stores an `empty string`.

I need the values to be stored **as they are**.

Any hints?

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
private string GetContent(
            NumericUserVariable templateNumericUserVariable,
            double doubleValue,
            CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {

            string placeholder = "#";
            if (!templateNumericUserVariable.IsDecimal)
            {
                return doubleValue.ToString();
            }

            string decimalPlaces = placeholder;

            if (templateNumericUserVariable.DecimalPlace > 0)
            {
                decimalPlaces = decimalPlaces.PadRight(

                    // templateNumericUserVariable.DecimalPlace - 1,
                    templateNumericUserVariable.DecimalPlace, '#');

                return doubleValue.ToString(placeholder + "." + decimalPlaces, cultureInfo);
            }

            return doubleValue.ToString(placeholder, cultureInfo);
        }
```

Comment: The method which I have posted returns the value that I have given as an input in a string format which is correct. The problem is when I add this return value to a List<string>.

Comment: @GrowWithWPF I find that very hard to believe. Adding a string to a `List<string>` should not cause characters to be removed from the string. Are you sure that you are actually observing the value returned from your `GetContent()` method and not the value of `doubleValue`?

Comment: @all - I have checked the code in-and-out. While adding to the list I am calling the function inside Add(). I will try a few permutations and combinations and will get back here if it does not work.

Comment: @all - I debugged in a clear way now. The problem is with the return value returned by 'return doubleValue.ToString(placeholder, cultureInfo);'. In my case the values passed to the ToString() method are 0.55, and {en-US}. But, it returns '.55'. Anything concerned to cultureInfo that is giving this sort of output?

Answer (score 0):

The "#" symbol specifically means that a digit is optional.  if what you want is at least one digit before the decimal point and then exactly two after then you should use "n2", "f2" or "0.00".

Comment: The method which I have posted returns the value that I have given as an input in a string format which is correct. The problem is when I add this return value to a List<string>. This is what is worrying me when I debugged the code.

Comment: `String` objects are immutable so if you are adding a `String` to a `List<string>` then it will not change.  If you see something other than what you added then it's because you are altering it somewhere along the line.  Show us how you are adding the values to the `List` and how you're extracting and using them.